# Mecurial trying to merge file with identical DAGs

Tags: mercurial

I have two repositories A and B.

I have pulled B into A.

For a given file on A hg log returns

*changeset:   40967:d7f84148b444

parent:      40966:afbd3f7ddeea

parent:      40730:8658f8a70bd5

user:        anon 

date:        Tue Nov 05 11:52:13 2013 +0000

summary:     merge from B


changeset:   40894:7f667abe8948

user:        anon

date:        Wed Oct 16 11:53:13 2013 +0100

summary:     Refactored some code*

and on B hg log return

*changeset:   40570:d7f84148b444

parent:      40402:afbd3f7ddeea

parent:      40569:8658f8a70bd5

user:        anon 

date:        Tue Nov 05 11:52:13 2013 +0000

summary:     merge from B


changeset:   39676:7f667abe8948

user:        anon

date:        Wed Oct 16 11:53:13 2013 +0100

summary:     Refactored some code*

The two graphs appear identical and there are no commits in A for the file that aren't in B and vice versa.

However merging the two heads in A requires a conflict to be resolved for this file.

I guess I'm missing something. What cases could cause Mercurial to think it needs to merge these two graphs?

Is there someway I can determine why Mercurial is trying to merge the file?

Comment: Are both commits equal (= does `hg st --rev d7f84148b444:d7f84148b444` returns no text)?

Comment: Yep that returns no text